# scala: adjacency matrix graphs

Tags: arrays, scala, graph, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to understand how to build graphs in Scala, till now I have this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object TestGraph {

  class Graph(vertices: Array[String], edges: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)]) {
    def size: Int = vertices.length
    def vertex(index: Int): String = vertices(index)
    def index(vertex: String): Int = vertices.indexOf(vertex)
    def printEdges(): Unit = { 
      for(v <- vertices) {
        print("vertex " + index(v) + ": ")
        for(e <- edges if(e._1 == index(v))) {
            print(e + " ")
        }
        println()
      }
    }
    def createAdjacencyMatrix() = {
      val adjacencyMatrix = Array.ofDim[Int](size, size)

    }
    def printAdjacencyMatrix(): Unit = {

    }
  }

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def vertices: Array[String] = Array("Seattle", "San Francisco", "Los Angeles",
        "Denver", "Kansas City", "Chicago", "Boston", "New York", 
        "Atlanta", "Miami", "Dallas", "Houston")

    def edges: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer(
        (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 5), 
        (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), 
        (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 10), 
        (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), 
        (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 10), 
        (5, 0), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7), 
        (6, 5), (6, 7), 
        (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8), 
        (8, 4), (8, 7), (8, 9), (8, 10), (8, 11), 
        (9, 8), (9, 11), 
        (10, 2), (10, 4), (10, 8), (10, 11), 
        (11, 8), (11, 9), (11, 10)
        )
        val graph = new Graph(vertices, edges)
        println("number of vertices in graph: " + graph.size)
        println("the vertex with index 1 is: " + graph.vertex(1))
        println("the index for Miami is: " + graph.index("Miami"))
        println("the edges for graph: "); graph.printEdges
        println("adjacency matric for graph: ");    
   }
}
```

I though to create an adjacency matrix and then to print it for the given graph. Is it a better way to fill the two dimensional array - something like I have done with `printEdges()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I allowed myself to refactor your code a bit:

```
class Graph(val vertex: IndexedSeq[String], edges: Seq[(Int, Int)]) {
    def size: Int = vertex.length
    val index: Map[String, Int] = vertex.zipWithIndex.toMap
    val adjacent = edges groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2))
    def adjacencyMatrix = adjacent mapValues (_.toSet) mapValues (0 to size map _)
    def printEdges: String = {
      for(idx <- 0 until size)
        yield f"vertex $idx: ${adjacent(idx) mkString " "}"
    } mkString "\n"
    def printAdjacencyList: String = adjacent mapValues (_ mkString ", ") mkString "\n"
    def printAdjacencyMatrix: String = adjacencyMatrix mapValues(_ mkString ", ") mkString "\n"
  }
```

and in `def main`:

```
println("number of vertices in graph: " + graph.size)
println("the vertex with index 1 is: " + graph.vertex(1))
println("the index for Miami is: " + graph.index("Miami"))
println("the edges for graph: ")
println(graph.printEdges)
println("adjacency list for graph: ")
println(graph.printAdjacencyList)
println("adjacency matrix for graph: ")
println(graph.printAdjacencyMatrix)
```

Comment: okii, you just pushed me to read and use more the ther Scala collections :D nice, thnxx a lot. I do not understand why the values are unordered when they get `groupBy` here `val adjacent = edges groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2))`?

Comment: @Valerin they contained in `HashMap` - the default implementation used in the `groupBy` inside `adjacent` definition. So they strangely ordered according to hash

Comment: If I want dynamically to add nodes on and to expand the graph is not efficient(possible) while the  `IndexedSeq` is immutable. Should I use `List` instead of `IndexedSeq` or `Arrays`?

Comment: @Valerin `immutable` does not means `inefficient` you could create new `IndexedSeq` adding new node via `:+` and new `Seq` prepending new edge via `+:`. If we talking about default implementations, i.e. `Vector` and `List` correspodingly, those operations would be pretty efficient.

Comment: With " not efficient" I was thinking that when I was trying to add elements, new copies of the collection was creating. Thnx for explanations. I am evaluating them so much!

Comment: @Valerin This exactly performance i was talking about. Take a look at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html. When you're appending to `Vector`  not whole collection is copied, most parts remains unchanged thanks to tree-like structure. When you're prepending to `List` nothing is copied, only single `Cons` is created.

Comment: @Valerin played a little bit with your code. Here the result https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/f7e522dd365afcfe87b4

Comment: wow great. When I have my version on what I am trying to achieve with this example I will share it, hopping to get feadback from you regarding the design also.

Comment: @Odomontis I added a Transpose method to my copy of your solution.  What do you think?  I added one line:   `def transpose = new Graph(vertex, edges.map(tupl => (tupl._2,tupl._1)))`